# SqlLite with real device not work but on simulator work

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swift4.2

I'm using [sqlLite with this library](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) so when I run on the simulator it works good but when I try to run to a real device it gave me this error

The Error:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8B355F9-6378-4862-9D06-84DA3FD06366/Documents
>   2019-01-02 19:54:23.476422+0200 Test[3626:1280621] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 42249 of [95fbac39ba]
>   2019-01-02 19:54:23.476491+0200 Test[3626:1280621] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:42249: (0) open(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8B355F9-6378-4862-9D06-84DA3FD06366/DocumentsTest.sqlite3) - Undefined error: 0
>   Can't connect to DB, Error is: Error Domain=SQLite.Result Code=0 "(null)", [:]

and this code that I make a connection to dp:

```
    import Foundation
    import SQLite
    import SQLite3

    class Database{

    static let shared = Database()
    public let connection: Connection?
    public let databaseName = "Test.sqlite3"

    init() {
        let dbPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first as! String
        print(dbPath)
        do{
            connection = try Connection("\(dbPath)\(databaseName)")
        }catch{
            connection = nil
            let nserror = error as NSError
            print("Can't connect to DB, Error is: \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a "/"

```
 connection = try Connection("\(dbPath)/\(databaseName)")
```